# Iterate through the key pair values with the help of for loop and print

Tags: shell

Trying to set up for loop in which I can parse the value with the corresponding key and print statement accordingly

```
> output.txt
Service1   Running
Service2   Running
Service3   Failed
```

Desired output:

```
Service1 is in Running state
Service2 is in Running state
Service3 is in Failed state
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **while** loop

```sh
while read name state; do
  echo "$name is in $state state"
done < output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of the fact that `printf` reuses its format specification until the output is exhausted

```
 printf "%s is in %s state\n" $(cat output.txt)
```

In case you have bash or zsh at your disposal, it can be written slightly simpler as:

```
 printf "%s is in %s state\n" $(<output.txt)
```